# Create SMTP Server to send, receiving E-mails (custom domain)

Tags: node.js, email, server, smtp, nodemailer

I gonna to create SMTP Server to send, receiving E-mails, using `nodemailer`

I have a custom domain from namecheap to do this

tried use this code but i don't receive any email on my Gmail account

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { SMTPServer } = require("smtp-server")

const server = new SMTPServer({
    onData(stream, session, callback) {
        console.log('test')
    },
    disabledCommands: ['AUTH'],
    secure: false
});

server.listen(25)

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: '192.168.1.2',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: '',
        pass: ''
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({ from: "support@myDomain.com", to: "myGmail@gmail.com", text: "text", subject: "subject" })
    .then(info => {
        console.log(info)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

log error:

```
test
Error: Message failed: 421 Timeout - closing connection
```

There any method to create smtp server using node js for send, receiving E-mails?

Comment: There are lots of robust, free, open source SMTP servers out there. Install one instead of trying to roll your own. (Note that random SMTP servers not supported by various DNS things are often flagged as likely spam so using one managed by your host in the first place is probably a better bet).

Comment: Give me examples
@Quentin

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers took me 5 seconds to find with Google